# How would you use a variable in filter function like this?

Tags: javascript, syntax

**Code:**

`const VARIABLE_NAME = test;`

`const results = json.VARIABLE_NAME.filter((result) => {...}`

**Expected Behavior:**

To filter `json.test`

**Actual Behavior:**

The following error: *"can't access property "filter", json.VARIABLE_NAME is undefined"*

Comment: `json[VARIABLE_NAME]`

Comment: what do you have in json object?. Assuming test exists on json and is a list. you can use something like this `json.[VARIABLE_NAME].filter((result) => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this:

`const results = json[VARIABLE_NAME].filter((result) => {...}`

Thanks to Nickolas Tower's comment.